# Logging all button clicks in WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, button, logging

I'm looking to add a log statement for every WinForms button click that the user clicks, and ideally, an indentifier of the parent form (such as the title bar). I have seen posts logging **all** mouse clicks, but i'm interested in just logging button clicks. I have read the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554314/event-for-click-in-any-button-c-windows-forms) and adapted it:

```
public class ButtonLogger
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ButtonLogger));
    public static void AttachButtonLogging(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (var button in controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Click += LogButtonClick;
        }
    }
    private static void LogButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        Logger.InfoFormat("Button clicked: {0} ({1})", button.Text, button.Parent.Text);
    }
}
```

This class is used at the end of a constructor in a form, e.g. :

```
ButtonLogger.AttachButtonLogging(this.Controls);
```

The problem I'm facing with this is that the Controls property doesn't seem to have a reference to my buttons. Presumably this is because the buttons aren't added directly to the form, but rather, another control that is in the Controls property. However, the Controls property only contains a single control, a ToolStrip.

Is there a way I can harness all of the buttons on a form, regardless of their parent container? My final goal is to add a log statement to my buttons, so if this can be accomplished some other way besides button click event methods, then I'm open to that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to search for buttons recursively:

```
public static void AttachButtonLogging(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (var control in controls.Cast<Control>())
    {
        if (control is Button)
        {
           Button button = (Button)control;
           button.Click += LogButtonClick;
        }
        else
        {
            AttachButtonLogging(control.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a situation in which we have a `TabControl` and some `Buttons` on some `TabPage`, we have to look in the `TabControl.TabPages`. I've experienced this problem, however if that's not the case of the OP, this code works OK.

Comment: @KingKing thanks, very good note. Frankly speaking I thought that tab pages will present in Controls of TabControl. Weird design!

Comment: Is this known to cause any performance issues when constructing the form? While this is recursion, it should be pretty light since there's a small amount of controls on a particular form (20 at most maybe). Also, since these are attached after the "real" event is attached to the button, it shouldn't delay the real processing you want to happen when the button is clicked.

Comment: @StealthRabbi I don't think it will cause some notable delay. I think some improvements can be done here (i.e. avoid controls collection initialization for each control), but you should try it - maybe all is OK as is

Comment: Can you think of any way this could be prioritized *before* the "real" events?  There are several issues with this approach of logging AFTER real events: first, if the button click opens a modal dialog, and then some actions within that dialog cause the application to crash, the click will never be logged (making it appear as though the crash came from the parent).  Similarly, clicks in the modal dialog will appear before the parent's click, aka out-of-order.  Finally, if the button click closes the parent dialog, button.Parent will be null.

Comment: (I couldn't figure out anyway to do this, without removing and re-adding all events, as the only thing in InitializeComponent() that occurs after button creation but before events are added is SuspendLayout(), which can't be overridden.  Hoping there's some cleaner solution...)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider is to create a subclass of the standard `Button` class, and let the buttons themselves do the logging. Of course, you'd have to go around and substitute all the buttons in the application for your own implementation, but it should be possible to do that with a global search+replace.

Here's an example implementation:

```
public class LoggerButton : Button
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerButton));

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        Logger.InfoFormat("Button clicked: {0} ({1})", this.Text, this.Parent.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes things more challenging for the designer, too. You'd have to create a custom toolbox pallete and use the custom button class instead of the built in one. It's an option for sure though, but perhaps a bit of a misuse of inheritance.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Really? I've never needed to do anything special for my custom controls to show up in the Visual Studio toolbox. But yeah, I'll agree that it's somewhat hacky.