# Log WinForm button clicks *before* firing events generated by the Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, delegates

I'm trying to figure out a way to have my WinForms application log every button-click to a file.  So far, the best solution I've found (from [Log all button clicks in Win Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949390/log-all-button-clicks-in-win-forms-app)) is something like:

```
public class ButtonLogger
{
    public static void AttachButtonLogging(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (var control in controls.Cast<Control>())
        {
            if (control is Button)
            {
                Button button = (Button)control;
                button.Click += LogButtonClick;
            }
            else
            {
                AttachButtonLogging(control.Controls);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LogButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        WriteLog("Click: " + button.Parent.Name.ToString() + "." + button.Name.ToString() + " (\"" + button.Text + "\")");
    }

    private static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then at the end of each form's constructor:

```
ButtonLogger.AttachButtonLogging(this.Controls);
```

While this is a great approach, it suffers from 3 major drawbacks, all due to the fact that the log events will always occur after the "real" events (created by the Designer):

1) If the button click opens a modal dialog, clicks within that dialog will be logged before the parent's click (aka logs appear out-of-order).  This is because the parent's click will only be logged once the modal dialog is closed, and thus after clicks within that dialog.

2) Similarly, if some action within that modal dialog causes the application to crash, the click that opened it will never be logged, making it appear as though the crash occurred in the parent.

3) If the button click closes the current dialog, button.Parent will be null (since the event that logs it will be fired *after* the dialog has already been closed by the "first" event).  Thus, we can't log the name of the form from which the "close" click came.

I've been racking my brain for a way to reverse the order (so log-events get fired before "real" events), but can't come up with anything **that doesn't preclude using the Designer**.  The issue is that the Designer both creates & assigns events within InitializeComponents(), which we can't edit.

Thoughts on possible (unsuccessful) solutions:

- Call AttachButtonLogging() from something that the Designer puts between button creation and adding events.  However, the only thing there is a call to SuspendLayout(), which isn't virtual and thus can't be overridden (and buttons haven't yet been added to the ControlCollection at that point).
- Have AttachButtonLogging() remove each button's existing events, add the log event, then re-add originals.  However, you can't enumerate a class's events from outside that class (i.e. AttachbuttonLogging can't enumerate a button's events).

It seems like something like this should be possible with some outside-the-box thinking, but I'm fresh out of ideas.  Note: the goal is to log the clicks **in a way that's not cumbersome when building new dialogs** - similarly to the solution above, but without the three mentioned pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options here, some more heinous than others. :) Unfortunately, in general, the more convenient a solution is, the more heinous it is.

**Option 1:** (least heinous)

Don't use the Designer (that's what we call the "GUI builder" in Visual Studio) to attach event handlers. Instead, write the code to attach the handlers for each button yourself, using a helper method in your click logger to automatically insert the needed handler:

```
class LogClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }

    public LogClickEventArgs(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

class ClickLogger
{
    public static event EventHandler<LogClickEventArgs> LogClick;

    public static void SubscribeClick(Control control, EventHandler handler)
    {
        control.Click += (_ClickHandler + handler);
    }

    private static void _ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogClick.Raise(null, new LogClickEventArgs(((Control)sender).Name));
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void Raise<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T e) where T : EventArgs
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Form` subclass:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClickLogger.SubscribeClick(button1, button_Click);
        ClickLogger.SubscribeClick(button2, button_Click);
        ClickLogger.SubscribeClick(button3, button_Click);

        ClickLogger.LogClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} -- {1}\r\n", e.DateTime, e.Name));
        };
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("==> clicked {0}\r\n", ((Control)sender).Name));
    }
}
```

IMHO, the Designer event-subscribing UI (double-click the event in the properties window to create and subscribe the handler) isn't really all *that* convenient. The above means instead of double-clicking in the Designer, you just add the appropriate lines of code to the `Form` constructor.

**Option 2:**

Use a custom `Button` sub-class, in which you override the `OnClick()` method and log the click:

```
class ClickLogger
{
    public static event EventHandler<LogClickEventArgs> LogClick;

    public static void NotifyClick(Control control)
    {
        LogClick.Raise(null, new LogClickEventArgs(control.Name));
    }
}
```

The custom `Button` sub-class:

```
public partial class LoggingButton : Button
{
    public LoggingButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickLogger.NotifyClick(this);
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

IMHO, this is reasonably convenient, but of course does have the drawback that you would have to sub-class any `Control` class for which you want to log the `Click` event. Your `LoggingButton` class can be manipulated in the Designer like any other `Control` though, and it's trivial to replace existing `Button` instances in the `*.Designer.cs` file with the custom one (easy search-and-replace).

**Option 3:** (most heinous)

Cheat, and use reflection to access private implementation details of the `Control` class, allowing yourself to directly manipulate the underlying data structure to insert your handler. This is a variation on the technique you're using now, but fixes your issue of which end of the invocation list your own logging handler winds up in:

```
class ClickLogger
{
    public static event EventHandler<LogClickEventArgs> LogClick;

    public static void AttachLogging<T>(ControlCollection controls) where T : Control
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control is T)
            {
                _AttachLoggingToControl(control);
            }

            AttachLogging<T>(control.Controls);
        }
    }

    private static void _AttachLoggingToControl(Control control)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        object eventClickObject = fi.GetValue(null);
        EventHandlerList handlerList = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(control);
        EventHandler clickHandlers = (EventHandler)handlerList[eventClickObject];

        handlerList[eventClickObject] = _ClickHandler + clickHandlers;
    }

    private static void _ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogClick.Raise(null, new LogClickEventArgs(((Control)sender).Name));
    }
}
```

In your `Form` sub-class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClickLogger.AttachLogging<Button>(Controls);

        ClickLogger.LogClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} -- {1}\r\n", e.DateTime, e.Name));
        };
    }
}
```

This is the closest to what you seem to be asking to do. However, it is theoretically very fragile, as it relies on implementation details that are not documented and are not necessarily fixed.

A major mitigating factor is that the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace is officially in "bug-fix only" mode. Also, Microsoft has open-sourced the code, which while no guarantee that implementations won't change, will mean that more people will start doing heinous things like this, increasing the reluctance with which Microsoft would change the implementation. And in any case, if they do change the implementation, because it's open-source it won't be a huge headache to fix your code to accommodate that.

There are other alternatives, even. But I think the above are the best options across the spectrum of balancing convenience versus hazard. :)

**EDIT:**

Yet another option occurs to me. I think you have enough to think about, so I won't fully flesh this one out, but I'll mention it in case you have specific thoughts about it…

**Option 4:**

Rather than focusing on the logging client code, you might consider looking at the logger implementation itself. For example, you could set up a message dependency relationship, in which certain messages are considered "dependent" on other messages or message categories/levels, and are not logged until one of those other messages is itself logged.

More specifically: you could classify the messages logged during the handling a `Click` event as dependent on the message logging the `Click` event itself. Call the former "level 1" messages, and the latter a "level 0" message. Implement the logging code so that it simply batches up "level 1" messages until it receives a "level 0" message, at which time it logs first the "level 0" message and then the queued-up "level 1" messages.

**Finally…** (I promise, last word on the subject)

I really should have mentioned this at the outset, but of course one of your choices is to not worry about this at all. In particular, it's not really clear to me why the `Click` event itself really is deserving of needing to be logged, and why the messages logged during the actual processing of the `Click` event are not in and of themselves sufficient to inform the reader of the log that the `Click` event happened.

In other words, yet another option is to simply not log `Click` events. This is obviously the simplest and easiest to implement, and the least likely to require maintenance in the future. :)

Comment: WONDERFUL and thorough answer!  Ugh, I feel bad now that I was already halfway through answering my own question when this popped up - though hopefully it'll be helpful to others :)  

Will respond to each option separately (comment character limit...)

Comment: Options 1 & 2 I actually had thought of, but I wanted to avoid changing too much of the existing (pretty extensive) codebase.  They also felt somewhat prone future developer error: as in the first, accidentally creating events in the Designer could mean random individual buttons not getting logged, and in the second, accidentally using "default" buttons (rather than subclasses) would mean the same.

Comment: Option 3 is genius (/heious? :)), and related to the solution I just came up with (well, at least in that they both use reflection).  Since you're obviously very knowledgeable about this, do you see anything wrong with mine?  It seems to me to be slightly safer, as rather than using reflection to manipulate the underlying data, it uses it just to access the buttons (before other events have been added).  Though I suppose it's always at risk of the Designer's method of code generation changing (i.e. not using SuspendLayout() at the same place)...

Comment: ...Actually, I just realized that my approach would result in multiple logs if SuspendLayout() is called at some other point in the form.  I suppose you could avoid that by checking the call stack in AttachButtonLogging(), and only do the action if it's being called from InitializeComponent()...but that's starting to get even more hacky.  Still, I'm very interested to hear your feedback... :)

Comment: Well, I think the issue with `SuspendLayout()` is a serious one. Checking the call stack is notoriously unreliable, as various compiler optimizations can prevent the method you're looking for from showing up (whether because the method itself was inlined, which can easily happen to very short methods unless you suppress inlining, or because the compiler optimized the return some other way...the stack tells you where you're going next, not necessarily where you came from).

Comment: ...For me, a bigger problem is that it uses member hiding, which is a known maintenance trap, as well as relies on an implementation detail much less robust than the `Events` list approach I offered. I'm not a huge fan of reflection as a _general_ solution (it's good for some very specific things), and even less of a fan of using it to access private implementation details of a type. But you're making a big assumption about where and even whether the `SuspendLayout()` method will be called, and that seems much more likely to break in hard-to-debug ways down the road.

Comment: ...Finally, note that you can easily catch developer errors in my first to options. #1: as part of the event-subscription logic, track the `Button` instances you attach handlers to (e.g. in a `HashSet<Button>`), and then when the subscription is done, check for any `Button` instances that are in the form but not in the set. #2: this is even simpler, as you can just enumerate the controls in the form and look for `Button` instances that aren't `LoggingButton` instances. Throw an exception if the test fails (for either option); someone can make a mistake, but it won't last long.

Comment: @Metal450: please see my most recent edit. And if you hadn't noticed them already, my recent comments, here in reply to yours.

Comment: Re: SuspendLayout(), I'm in full agreement here.  I guess your Option 3 is definitely better :)

Comment: Re: catching bugs in 1 & 2, very good points.  I still think I prefer #3 though, just because it requires fewer changes throughout the codebase - i.e. differences introduced by this change are pretty localized to the logger, rather throughout.

Comment: Option 4: Interesting approach.  Seems like this would be poor for debugging though, as it's batching-up logs that might not get written by the time the software crashes; i.e. it solves issue #1 in my original question, but not #2.  In addition, if Im' understanding correctly, it would hold back logging anything that occurs in in "modal dialog 2" until it returns to "parent dialog 1" - making modal dialog 2 un-debuggable (via logs).  Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Finally: not sure what you mean by "why the messages logged during the actual processing of the Click event."  What messages logged?  This is what I set out to do: to have mesages logged during the click event... :P

Comment: @Metal450: You are correct; option #4 buffers more messages, so there is a greater risk of losing some. My point about "why the messages logged..." is that the issue here is that there is already logged output as part of the processing of the `Click` event (i.e. the messages that without some solution wind up in the log file _before_ the message logging the `Click` event itself). My question (mostly rhetorical, in the sense that it's doubtful I'd follow up on the answer :) ) is why aren't those messages sufficient to indicate that the `Click` event itself happened. Why a specific logged event?

Comment: Oh, I got it.  But no, that's not sufficient.  Just a simple example: a form is performing some continuous operation (i.e. streaming some data off the disk).  It hits corrupt data, and crashes.  VERSUS: form is performing continuous operation; user clicks to open a modal dialog, & that dialog crashes the program while trying to init.  Since there'd be no record of the user opening the modal dialog (until AFTER it finishes), the latter situation would yield the same log as the former: it's misleading about when the program crashed (in form 1 or dialog 2?)

Answer (score 5):

Just use [IMessageFilter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [Application.AddMessageFilter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) to get messages **before** they get sent to your app.  This will work for all buttons in all forms of your app (no matter how deeply they are nested).  It will even work for buttons added dynamically at run-time.  **The best part is, you don't need to change anything at all with your existing code and controls.**  All you have to do is add the message filter *once* from the Load() event of your startup form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(new ButtonLogger());
    }

}

public class ButtonLogger : IMessageFilter
{

    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP || (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP && ((int)m.WParam == 32 || (int)m.WParam == 13)))
        {
            Control ctl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
            if (ctl is Button)
            {
                LogButtonClick((Button)ctl);
            }
        }
        return false; // allow normal processing of all messages
    }

    private void LogButtonClick(Button btn)
    {
        WriteLog("Click: " + btn.Parent.Name.ToString() + "." + btn.Name.ToString() + " (\"" + btn.Text + "\")");
    }

    private void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Without a doubt the best solution I've seen, and man, so much more versatile!  Accepted.  Thanks for saving the day :)

Comment: @Metal450: I should note that this doesn't actually answer the question that was asked. The `Click` event can be raised for reasons other than these specific window messages, and these specific window messages do not necessarily result in a `Click` event. It's a good solution if it works in your specific scenario, but when it doesn't work, it will be similarly difficult to notice, debug, and fix as for some of the other solutions considered here.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, True.  This wouldn't catch it if you did a PerformClick() via code for instance.  Or possibly if someone was automating your UI directly with APIs or a third-party tool and used different messages.  For **standard** human user interaction generated by mouse and/or keyboard events, though, it should be fine (if that is even the end goal?!).  It really depends on how it will be used and why I suppose...

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I tend to agree.  In truth I was very torn over whose answer to accept, because yours is SO comprehensive and well thought-out, but this one seems so much simpler & works wonderfully for my application (with NO per-form code needed).  So while this is the solution I'll use in my code, upon review I do think yours is probably a more direct answer to the question as it was phrased.

Comment: One more small caveat: this will falsely log an event if you click a button, drag the mouse out of the button's region, then release. (Easy enough to test for, just thought I'd mention :))

Comment: Things are always different when you've got a working application versus if you're building it from the ground up.  Definitely some trade-offs to consider here.  Accepted solution doesn't really matter to me; I just like sharing different approaches and code.  I thought it fit the bill of "outside-the-box thinking" quite nicely.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've (finally) figured out a solution (explanation follows).  First, the logger becomes:

```
public class ButtonLogger
{
    public static void AttachButtonLogging(Form form)
    {
        foreach (var field in form.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            if (field.GetValue(form) is Button)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Button button = (Button)field.GetValue(form);
                button.Click += LogButtonClick;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LogButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        WriteLog("Click: " + button.Parent.Name.ToString() + "." + button.Name.ToString() + " (\"" + button.Text + "\")");
    }

    private static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then we do the following in each form:

```
public new void SuspendLayout()
{
    base.SuspendLayout();
    ButtonLogger.AttachButtonLogging(this);
}
```

The logic is that the Designer inserts a call to SuspendLayout() after creating each button, but before adding events to buttons - thus, if we can add our logging events at this time, they will be fired before the designer's events.  However, at this time the buttons have not yet been added to the form's list of controls.  So instead, we use reflection to examine all of the form's fields, and for each one that's a button, we add our event.

Some more testing is needed, but for now, it seems to be working nicely!