# c# statement not executing when while querying

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio

i can't seem to figure out why the following statements are not executing. the oracle statement works perfectly in sql developer.
i am using this button to insert NEW data from 'neft_temp' into 'bbbt'

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=KBETEST; Persist Security Info=TRUE; User ID=dbo; Password=dbo123; Unicode=True");
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

        string str = "insert into bbbt(bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,brn_addr,brn_loc,brn_stat,brn_city,coun_code,remarks,ifsc_code,rtgs_stat) select substr(ifsc_code,1,4), substr(ifsc_code,5), n.branch_name, n.address1, n.district, n.state, n.city, 'IN', n.bank_name, n.ifsc_code,n.status from neft_temp n where ifsc_code in (SELECT ifsc_code FROM neft_temp MINUS SELECT ifsc_code FROM bbbt)";
        con.Open();
        da.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(str, con);
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Dispose();
        button4.PerformClick();
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the button is hooked up the event??

Comment: First, I'm hard-pressed to imagine that you really want to open a database connection every time someone clicks a button.  But if you are saying this code is not being executed, that implies that your procedure is not getting called.  If that is the case, you'd need to debug that and figure out why the procedure isn't being called.

Comment: does the code execute? are there any exceptions?

Comment: @JustinCave opening a connection is not a problem; most providers implement pooling

Comment: When you say 'not executing' what exactly do you mean? If you put a breakpoint on the opening brace does it get hit?

Comment: @MarcGravell - I'm assuming that there is a connection pool.  I would be hard-pressed to believe that you'd want the connection string floating around in every button click method that interacted with the database.

Comment: @JustinCave oh, indeed, the connection string shouldn't be there - I assume that is just for illustration code. But: your complaint was "open a database connection every time someone clicks a button" - which *simply isn't an issue* (if the provider implements pooling) - in fact, it *is the recommended usage*

Comment: @Jonny yes, the open braces does not get hit when i put the break point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** an answer to the question (hence community wiki) - I'm still waiting on more context (re "not executing") for that - but this is just an advisory in terms of reducing the moving parts, and avoiding side issues (for example, the current code doesn't close the connection if an exception is thrown):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=KBETEST; Persist Security Info=TRUE; User ID=dbo; Password=dbo123; Unicode=True"))
    using(var cmd = new OracleCommand(@"
insert into bbbt(bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,brn_addr,brn_loc,brn_stat,brn_city,coun_code,remarks,ifsc_code,rtgs_stat)
select substr(ifsc_code,1,4), substr(ifsc_code,5), n.branch_name, n.address1, n.district, n.state, n.city, 'IN', n.bank_name, n.ifsc_code,n.status from neft_temp n where ifsc_code in (SELECT ifsc_code FROM neft_temp MINUS SELECT ifsc_code FROM bbbt)", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }       
    button4.PerformClick();
}
```

Note that the data-adapter added nothing here, and there were multiple `IDisposable` types that weren't using `using`.

Comment: marc, i have a similar code running which leads to this event. it executes and passes on to this one, but for some reason, the program breaks here and doesn't move forward. i can't seem to understand why..

Comment: @ShilpaGeorge well, again: is there an exception? if so, what does the exception say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the button into the button3_Click method. You can either do this in code (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-added-dynamically)) or in the Visual Studio IDE (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554314/event-for-click-in-any-button-c-windows-forms)).

Comment: @jonny.. is this what you mean by 'hook' button into button3_click ?
private void checknewbank_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("..");
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

            string str = ... con.Open();
            da.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(str, con);
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Dispose();
            button3.PerformClick();

        }
this button triggers the calling of button 3 which is not executing.. please correct me if i'm wrong.ty

Comment: i'm sorry for that mess

Comment: but as you can see, "button3.performclick()" hooks it to the button

Comment: The current button3_Click method that you have is fine (although consider adding the using blocks in the other answer). You just need to link together the button and the button3_Click method. In an initialise method you need to do something like 

button3.Click += button3_Click